# operator OR resolving to false?

Tags: javascript

I just noticed a weird behaviour. I am sure not the first to notice it but I would like to understand what is going on.

Why does `true || true ? 'foo' : 'bar'` resolves to `'foo'`

And what makes it different from `true || (true ? 'foo' : 'bar')` that resolves to `true`?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tgdx5u8s/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key difference is that without the parentheses, `||` has precedence over `?:`. In more detail:

**First case**

```
true || true ? 'foo' : 'bar'
```

due to `||` having precedence over `?:` is equivalent to:

```
(true || true) ? 'foo' : bar'
```

The `||` operator returns the left operand if it is is truthy, which in this case it is (otherwise it would return the right operand).

So this resolves to:

```
true ? 'foo' : 'bar'
```

which resolves to `'foo'`.

**Second case**

```
true || (true ? 'foo' : 'bar')
```

resolves to:

```
true || 'foo'
```

Again the `||` operator returns the left operand if it is is truthy, which in this case it is. So this resolves to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

[`... || ...` binds tighter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than `... ? ... : ...`, so your statement is parsed as:

```
(true || true) ? 'foo' : 'bar'
```

`true || true` is `true`, so you get `'foo'`.

Answer (score 2):

**About the first one**

```
 true || true ? 'foo' : 'bar'
```

Would be the same as:

```
(true || true) ? 'foo' : 'bar'
```

So essentially:

```
true ? 'foo' : 'bar'
```

**About the second one**

```
true || (true ? 'foo' : 'bar');
```

Would be the same as:

```
true || 'foo';
```

So `true` or whatever other thing is `true` (no need to even evaluate `'foo'` for that one...)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of order of operation.  Usually || is handled before ?: but when you add the braces then the expression inside the braces is evaluated before ||.

So the first ends up true ? 'foo' : 'bar' and the second ends up as true || 'foo'

Can find order at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not that I want to go against the majority but the precedence of `||` is not the reason for the observed behavior but the precedence of the parentheses. The construct `logical or expression '?' expression ':' conditional expression` is not much more than a slightly restricted `IF '(' expression ')' statement ELSE statement` once-along time ago, when memory was measured in kilobytes, the difference between a fully optimizing compiler run and one without was measured in hours and the monitors had 50 rows with 80 characters if you were lucky-implemented to make things simpler and smaller for the computer and the compiler. Not the user.

So if you use the `?:;` you don't need no `if`, no parentheses around the expression after the `if`, and no curly brackets if you have more than one line after the `if`. The lack of need of parentheses is, in my humble experience, the reason for most, well, let's call them irritations.

To translate your problem into something more readable:

```
var a;
if(true || true){
   a = 'foo';
} else {
   a = 'bar';
}
```

The second one throws an error because of its incorrect syntax instead of letting you scratch your head:

```
var a;
if(true || if(true){a='foo';}else{a='bar';})/*noop*/;
```

The advantage of the `?:;` construct is its ability to fill the right side of a declaration. The first example can be easily reduced to:

```
a = true || true ? 'foo' : 'bar';
```

I find it more readable if you add the parentheses despite being redundant:

```
a = (true || true) ? 'foo' : 'bar';
```

But that's probably more a matter of personal taste.